# What is the difference between the definition a closed set and a non-open set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let set $S$ be open, meaning that $\forall s \in S$, $\exists \varepsilon > 0$ such that $(s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon) \subset S$. In other words, there is always some small $\varepsilon$ that allows for the neighborhood of $s$ to belong to $S$ (correct my wording if I'm wrong). If it were closed, then $S^c$ would be open. I'm thinking that the definition of a non-open set would be $\exists s \in S$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $(s - \varepsilon, s + \varepsilon) \not\subset S$.

This doesn't make sense to me since $s \in (s-\varepsilon, s+\varepsilon) \not\subset S$ but $s$ also belongs to $S$... Also, what if there were elements less than $\max S$ and suppose $s = \max S$? Then there would be some $c$ where, given a small $\delta > 0$, $s \geq c > s-\delta$ and $c\in S$. If we set $\delta = \epsilon$, what if there was a $c \not\in S$ (not guaranteed however...) Perhaps the definition is flawed, but I would appreciate some guidance to finding a workable definition so I can prove if $S$ is not open, then $\exists \{s_n\}$ (where $ s_n \in S^c$) and $\exists x \in S$ such that $s_n \rightarrow x$.

Comment: How does setting $\varepsilon = \delta$ prove that $c \notin S$?

Comment: Is it better to say that $c$ has the possibility to be in $S$ if $S := \{ r \in \mathbb R \mid r \leq s \}$?

Comment: I'm just not sure where the contradiction is. Are you saying that if $A$ is not a subset of $B$, then $x \in A \implies x \notin B$? Because this isn't true.

Comment: Oh, so if $\exists x \in A$ and that same $x \not\in B$, is that enough to say that $A \not\subset B$? Then, there wouldn't be a contradiction in the first place because having at least one element in $(s-\varepsilon, s+\varepsilon)$ that doesn't belong to S satisfies $(s-\varepsilon, s+\varepsilon)\not \subset S$?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you have a contradiction. Take your $c$ for example. You assumed that (1) $c \in (s - \varepsilon, s + \varepsilon)$, (2) $(s - \varepsilon, s + \varepsilon)$ is not a subset of $S$, and (3) $c \in S$. You then claimed that $c \notin S$. This doesn't follow from the assumptions; just because $c \in (s - \varepsilon, s + \varepsilon) \nsubseteq S$ does *not* imply $c \notin S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your non-open set definition is correct.

With respect to your doubts, $(s-\varepsilon, s+\varepsilon)\not\subset S$ means there **exists** an element in that interval that doesn't belong to $S$. The fact that $s\in S$ does not contradict this.

Secondly, if $a=\sup(S)\in S$, then $S$ is not open, because for every $\varepsilon>0$, $a+\varepsilon/2\in(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$ but $a+\varepsilon/2\notin S$. This does not mean $S$ is closed, take for instance $S=(0,1]$.

Now, if $S$ is not open, then $S^c$ is not closed. But there is a famous characterisation that says a set $A$ is closed iff every convergent sequence with terms in $A$ has its limit in $A$. Thus, we may find a sequence $\{s_n\}$ in $S^c$ such that it converges to some $s\notin S^c$, that is, $s\in S$.

Comment: This clarifies a lot of my doubts!

On the note of finding such a sequence, say $B>a$ and $a = \sup S \in S$. Can we construct a sequence where $s_1 \in (a,B)$, $s_2 \in (a,a+(B-a)/2)$, $\dots$, $s_n \in (a, a+(B-a)/(2^{n-1}))$ ? This would mean $a - (B-a)/(2^{n-1}) < a < s_n < a + (B-a)/(2^{n-1})$. Also, given $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists M>0$ for $n>M$ where $|s_n-a|<\varepsilon$ and choose $M=\max\{1+\log_2\frac{B-a}{\varepsilon},0\}$. Then $|s_n-a|<\frac{B-a}{2^{M-1}}=\varepsilon$, proving $s_n \rightarrow a$? (sorry for the compressed logic)

Comment: If $a=\sup S \in S$, you could just take $s_n=a+1/n$

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes more concise sense--then I could just choose $M=1/\varepsilon$. I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem. If you don't have any more doubts, please accept the answer so the question doesn't appear unanswered to other users.